# Is there any way to extend the column limit in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Libreoffice Calc currently limits column import to around 1,000 columns; Excel allows about 16,000.

Is there any way to extend this limit on Libreoffice?

Comment: What version of Calc are you using?  Did you upgrade to 7.0.2?

Comment: I asked this before v7 was released, I believe; the capability has since been added, as per the comment below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.

> > How to enable support for very large spreadsheets in Libreoffice 7 Calc?
> > Via the following steps in Tools -> Options...:
>
> - First under LibreOffice -> Advanced, check Enable experimental features
>   (may be unstable),
> - After a restart, under LibreOffice Calc -> Defaults, check Enable very
>   large spreadsheets (16m rows, 16384 cols).